# Add map with list to Form for mobile app?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

This is a very basic question, but I have no idea how to be begin, so please bear with me.

I'm a C# software developer, so I'm very familiar with the VS IDE and with Windows and Web development. But I have never developed a mobile application.

With that said, I came up with an idea which is essentially a screen with a map and a bunch of pins, and a list that represents each pin. It will run in an iphone and android phone. It will look something like below.

I decided to develop it in Xamarin because 1) I've worked with VS for many years so I understand how it works, 2) I can develop *one app* in Xamarin that can run both in ios and android.

I understand that it may be a very basic question, but I have no idea where to start. I also have experience with development, so I don't want to go thru the *Hello World* example. Finally, I also have a full-time job, so my limited free time would be used to completing this particular app.

So my question is: where do I start?

[image]

Comment: there are hundreds of free tutorials, sample apps, webcasts, e-books, etc on Xamarin - including examples that use Maps

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map

Answer (score 1):

First thing first. You should get yourself familiar with Mobile Development(app life cycle, patterns etc.) by creating few sample applications (since you stated you were developing in Visual Studio using c# before it should be quick procedure for you). You can find documentation and sample codes on official Xamarin site:

[Xamarin Website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/)

Next get yourself familiar with MVVM pattern and MVVM frameworks to write applications using modern patterns and modern practises. I personally recommend MVVMCross or MVVMFresh.

[Data Binding from Official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)

[FreshMVVM with Samples](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm)

Then get yourself familiar with Xamarin.Forms maps. It's a nice library that allows you to use one code and share them across 2 platforms. Google Maps official apis are also good but they are platform specific.

[Xamarin Forms Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map)

Enjoy and welcome to the Dark Side ;)